# Making codeigniter admin to rule them all

Tags: codeigniter

I want to make a codeigniter admin/cms to manage all my clients front ends, i want to separate the admin application in two folder, the generic folder, that all other will extend or use, and the client site admin, that i will make for the client needs.
Can it be done?

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what it is you are trying to achieve. E.g. what are the 'client front ends' and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recommend the WireDesigns HMVC - https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

This will allow you to make 2 modules Front-End / Admin in each module it follows hte same rules of Controller / Model / View which you can build up each one independently but to work together.

Technically though you could just create 2 folders in your controllers folder called Frontend / Admin, and build your controllers right there.

but if you looking for cleaner ogranization, try the HMVC